# Managing Multiple Observation at the same time stamp timeseries forecasting deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset timeseries forecasting that includes the categorical columns and numeric as well.

here is a sample of it

```
Date | categorical _fature_1 |categorical _fature_2|  Feature_1_numeric | feature_2_numeric | price

1-1-2020 | USA | A | 5.5 | 7.6 | 100

1-1-2020 | USA | B | 8.3 | 1.7| 20

1-1-2020 | USA | C | 3.6 | 2.1 | 17

1-2-2020 | USA | D | 5.5 | 7.6 | 40

1-2-2020 | USA | E | 77.5 | 35 | 22

1-2-2020 | USA | F | 69.5 | 2 | 22
```

as you can see in the sample in the date lets pick up the **1-1-2020** we have multiple observations at the same date .

i want to predict the **Price** column as a **Y_label** and taking the **categorical _fature_1**, **categorical _fature_2**, **Feature_1_numeric**, and **Feature_2_numeric** as the **X_features**

so from my understanding as im using **multiple features** for time series Forecasting predicting the **Price** column this is called **Multivariate Time-Series Forecasting**

My Question is

1-how can i manage the multiple observations at the same time from the different features as we saw for example in **1-1-2020** we have **three** different observations

2-i believe if we have multiple observations at the same time/date then we have a new kind of Time-series forecasting what is it Multi-timestep Multivariate Time-Series Forecasting or what ???

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is multivariate time series forecasting indeed, and you need to train your model on the past time of the features as well as the interdependencies between them.

One common solution is Vector Auto Regression (VAR).

They are basically models that calculates both time and values interdependencies using a matrix:

[image: Source: wikipedia]

Source: Wikipedia

Here is an overview for 3 features and second order:
[image]
Source: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/vector-autoregression-examples-python/

In your case, you will consider Y1 as feature_1, Y2 as feature_2 and Y3 as price.

This will calculate the interactions between Y1, Y2 and Y3, and you will get the prediction you want for the 3 of them, including Y3.

There is a library in Python, Statsmodel, that has a VAR function [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html).

VAR is a good start, but it is a linear algorithm, i.e you may not have good results if your features are complex to predict.

If you have complex features, there are non linear algorithms that would perform better, like [Multivariate LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) and [Random Forest](https://towardsdatascience.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-random-forest-2372f3ecbad1).

Comment: thanks for your answer Nicolas, from your answer you mean that i should consider **categorical _fature_1**,  **categorical _fature_2** are Y_labels just like price 
categorical _fature_1 --> y_label_1,
categorical _fature_2 --> y_label_2,
price --> y_label_3.   
and the X_features are 

Feature_1_numeric --> X_feature_1
,
Feature_2_numeric --> X_feature_2
is that what you mean ????

Comment: VAR works differently than most models like LSTM or Random Forest: there is no proper objective feature. You merely compare curves between each other and you try to make predictions based on those comparisons. Consequently, you just have Y features. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression

Comment: lets pretend that im working on LSTM not VAR that means my y_labels are (categorical _fature_1, categorical _fature_2, price)  and X_features  Feature_1_numeric , Feature_2_numeric ..............................or what ??

Comment: Yes. The shape will be 1 timestep + the X features (input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]) ), one Y/Price output (=Dense(1)) . You can reuse the page above about LSTM.

Comment: and this regardless the multiple observations at the same time, because the LSTM will handle this using its multiple window sizes ( number of filters) that given to the LSTM parameters???

Comment: Yes it will, but why would you have different window sizes?

Comment: here is my model .........................................
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(8))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

Comment: it's just : model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam') (see link above)

Comment: and too many dropouts may alter your predictions. You can try them afterwards but I would suggest with a lower value (0.1)

Comment: thank you Nicolas, i would ask you another question =D, my training set size equal to 300K, the batch_size can be 128 or lower than this values or upper than this values......................also for the time-steps i made one time step should i increase it or decrease it, i just want to get the intuition

Comment: Batch size of 128 seems correct. LSTM can be trained over thousands of steps, but it recognized patterns over 500 steps maximum: This is a hardware limitation of LSTM. The LSTM would learn 1 time step by 1 timestep the input features. Consequently, you should keep 1 time step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128249/discussion-between-mohamed-el-abdou-and-nicolas-m).

Comment: may i ask another question regarding the loss function learning
First im really thank full for your great answers......here is my qustion.....the loss function after the third epoch is stopped to learn in other word the value still remains constantly, i used your sugessted model, do you have any recommendations to take it into my consideration or check somethings ???
also there is something wearied that the error is very very small value which gives me the sense that there is definitely some problem

Comment: I can't help without more details, sorry: please post another question and do not hesitate to add code and the result you have.